# Meta box not saving

Tags: custom-post-types, php, metabox

I am following [Noel Tock's](http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/custom-post-types-events-pt1/) tutorial on making an Events CPT and so far I was able to show the custom columns and the custom meta box.

The problem now is that I cannot save the data inside the meta box. I am confused as I have found that when I press the update button, the values won't stay on the fields and won't reflect on the custom columns.
The code is similar to the tutorial though.

The custom columns:

```
function events_custom_columns($column){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom();
switch($column){
    case 'event_col_type':
            $eventcats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'event_type');
            $ev_cat_html = array();
            if($eventcats){
                foreach($eventcats as $eventcat)
                    array_push($ev_cat_html, $eventcat->name);
                    echo implode($ev_cat_html, ', ');
            }
            else {
                echo 'None';
            }
    break;
    case 'event_date':
            $start = $custom['event_start_date'][0];
            $end = $custom['event_end_date'][0];

            $startdate = date('F j, Y', $start);
            $enddate = date('F j, Y', $end);

            echo $startdate . '<br><em>' . $enddate . '</em>';
    break;
    case 'event_time':

            $time_formtt = get_option('time_format');
            $starttime = $custom['event_start_date'][0];
            $endtime = $custom['event_end_date'][0];

            $startT = date($time_formtt, $starttime);
            $endT = date($time_formtt, $endtime);

            echo $startT . ' - ' . $endT;

    break;
    case 'event_location':
            echo $custom['event_location'][0];
    break;
}
```

}

The custom meta box:
    add_action('admin_init', 'events_admin_init');

```
function events_admin_init(){
    add_meta_box('event_meta', 'Event Details', 'event_details_meta', 'events', 'normal', 'default');
}

function event_details_meta(){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);

$meta_SDate = $custom['event_start_date'][0];
$meta_EDate = $custom['event_end_date'][0];
$meta_STime = $meta_SDate;
$meta_ETime = $meta_EDate;

$time_format = get_option('time_format');

if($meta_SDate == null){
    $meta_SDate = time();
    $meta_EDate = $meta_SDate;
    $meta_STime = 0;
    $meta_ETime = 0;
}

$sd = date("D, M d, Y", $meta_SDate);
$ed = date("D, M d, Y", $meta_EDate);
$st = date($time_format, $meta_STime);
$et = date($time_format, $meta_ETime);

echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "events_nonce1" id = "events_nonce1" value = "' . wp_create_nonce('events_nonce1') . '>"';

?>

    <ul style = "list-style-type: none;">
        <li><label>Start Date: </label><input name = "event_start_date" class = "dp_date" value = "<?php echo $sd; ?>"</li>
        <li><label>End Date: </label><input name = "event_end_date" class = "dp_date" value = "<?php echo $ed; ?>"</li>
        <li><label>Start Time: </label><input name = "event_start_time" value = "<?php echo $st; ?>"</li>
        <li><label>End Time: </label><input name = "event_end_time" value = "<?php echo $et; ?>"</li>
    </ul>

<?php
}
```

Here's the save function:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_events_deets');

function save_events_deets(){
   global $post;

   if(!wp_verify_nonce1($_POST['events_nonce1'], 'events_nonce1'))
   {    return $post -> ID;}

   if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
       return;

   if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post -> ID))
   {    return $post -> ID;}

   if(!isset($_POST['event_start_date'])){
       return $post;
   }

   $updStartD = strtotime($_POST['event_start_date'] . $_POST['event_start_time']);
   update_post_meta($post -> ID, 'event_start_date', $updStartD);


   if(!isset($_POST['event_end_date'])){
       return $post;
   }

   $updEndD = strtotime($_POST['event_end_date'] . $_POST['event_end_time']);
   update_post_meta($post -> ID, 'event_end_date', $updEndD);   
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have [debugging with logging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG), run the code again, then check `wp-content/debug.log` and report back with the errors (if any).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I found 2 same errors, _Undefined index_ on 

`$meta_SDate = $custom['event_start_date'][0];`
`$meta_EDate = $custom['event_end_date'][0];`

Comment: check `events_nonce` vs. `events_nonce1`?

Comment: @majick i have changed it. but problem still persists.

Comment: is this the actual code now? `wp_verify_nonce` is a function but `wp_verify_nonce1` is not...  the previous mismatch was only in the nonce name not the function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using single values anyway, how about trying just:

```
$meta_SDate = get_post_meta($post->ID,'event_start_date',true);
$meta_EDate = get_post_meta($post->ID,'event_end_date',true);
```

Also note the following lines will need a space to separate the posted values so `strtotime` can work properly:

```
$updStartD = strtotime(trim($_POST['event_start_date']) . ' ' . trim($_POST['event_start_time']));
$updEndD = strtotime(trim($_POST['event_end_date']) . ' ' . trim($_POST['event_end_time']));
```

I have added `trim` to remove left and right whitespace just in case too.

Comment: it's still not doing anything after i changed it to that...

Comment: have you checked the database table to see if the values are actually saving? it would narrow it down to whether it is a saving or retrieving problem.

Comment: yes i did, and the values weren't saving. i am using a plugin for now, but i am also eager to know the root of the problem.